# No data reaches server

Tags: ios, upload, asihttprequest

I am trying to upload images and documents to a remote server. The remote server has PHP page for handling uploads.The request is sent successfully but nothing reaches server. I am using ASIHTTPREQUEST. here is the code :

```
-(void)uploadFile
{
    NSString *resume =@"0";
    NSUserDefaults *userCredentials =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *userName =[userCredentials objectForKey:@"userName"];
    NSLog(@"Media Type : %@",selectedMediaType);
    NSLog(@"User Name : %@",[userCredentials objectForKey:@"userName"]);
    NSLog(@"File Name : %@",delegate.fileName);
    NSString *stringToAppend =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mediatype=%@&file_name=%@&usrname=%@&filesize=%@&sha256sum=%@&resume=%@",selectedMediaType,delegate.fileName,userName,fileSize,fileSHA256Sum,resume];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://briareos.code20.com/putmedia.php?%@",stringToAppend ]];
    uploadMedia = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"URL WITH INFO %@",url);
    [uploadMedia appendPostData:dataToUpload];
    [uploadMedia setDelegate:self];
    [uploadMedia setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];
    [uploadMedia startAsynchronous];

}
```

Can someone let me know what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error? Try to append

```
NSError *error = [uploadMedia error];
if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [uploadMedia responseString];
} else {
    // catch your error here
}
```

to your code